# Why isn't find excluding files with the given regex?

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, find

I'm trying to find all files under `/mnt/Storage` *not* under `/mnt/Storage/.Snapshots`. The following works:

```
find /mnt/Storage | egrep -v "^/mnt/Storage/\.Snapshots"
```

But the following does not:

```
find /mnt/Storage -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex "/mnt/Storage/\.Snapshots.*"
```

even though the two should, to best of my knowledge, be equivalent.

It also seems that removing the -not in the second expression resulted in files only under `.Snapshots` being listed, so it's almost like the regex is right but I'm using `-not` wrong... except I don't see how.

What grave error have I made with the second command? I'm actually trying to craft a better solution using `-prune` but I still don't understand why my attempt here doesn't work.

Comment: The "better solution" would be `find /mnt/Storage \( -name .Snapshots -prune \) , -print`, I think.

Comment: Have you tried: find /mnt/Storage -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex "/mnt/Storage/\.Snapshots.*"

Comment: @snowdude - didn't work :/

Comment: @jaymmer Odd, it did work for me on CentOS

Comment: It does work for me on Debian 9.